# Kalanchoe lower leaves yellowing

Tags: houseplants, leaves, kalanchoe

I have a pretty big Kalanchoe and it looks 99% green, but the bottom leaves are starting to brown and die. Not many of them, just like one at a time I think. Is that normal? If I look online, it says I'm doing something wrong. Am I? It just keeps growing (though the flowers are fewer and fewer, which might be because their season is ending) and I'm watering it around once a week (if I do it twice a week it stops growing, so I've settled for that). It's also really hot and sunny outside so it's been getting lots of light and if anything, the bottom leaves are the ones not getting much light

Lower leaves and whole plant pictures

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but your plant looks healthy and nice to me. I think it is natural that the leaves at the bottom, closest to the soil will die off eventually. It does not seem to happening on a mass scale so I would not worry too much.

Regarding the watering I think you could water it even less frequently. Only when the soil gets pretty dry. From [How to Grow Kalanchoes](https://www.miraclegro.com/en-us/library/indoor-gardening/how-grow-kalanchoes):

> When the top 2 inches of soil is dry (all the way dry, not just sort of dry), it’s time to water. Indoors, this will probably mean you’ll only need to water every 2 or 3 weeks, but be sure to check regularly.